# Proguard "Missing type parameter" on Samsung device

Tags: android, gson, proguard, android-4.4-kitkat, dexguard

I`ve published an android app, obfuscated by dexguard. Everything seems to be fine, except for the Galaxy Tab 3 10.1 and only with Android 4.4, which is the only device, that reports errors to the developer console.

I get following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing type parameter.
at com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.<init>(:62)
at com....util.Helper$2.<init>(:398)
```

Code in class Helper.java and line 398

```
return (Config) getSerializable(context, CONFIG, new TypeToken<Config>(){}.getType());
```

My dexguard rules:

```
# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
# path to the config class:  com/.../models/config/Config.java;
-keep class com....models.** { *; }

-keepattributes Signature
```

Not only that I can not reproduce the error myself (i also have an Galaxy Tab 3 with Android 4.2, update not available yet), it only concerns the above mentioned device.

Comment: I have this exact issue on Samsung Galaxy Tab 3's, not entirely sure what to do! Also using dexguard.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue only on Tab 3 10.1" and i'm using DexGuard too. But apparently this happens inside the twitter core library and not in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was to avoid the use of the TypeToken and updating dexguard to the latest version.

For example:

Instead of

```
new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<Object>(){}.getType());
```

use this

```
new Gson().fromJson(json, Object.class);
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for following up. I did the same thing, and it appears to be working. However, I was using parameterized types, e.g., `new TypeToken<List<User>>(){}.getType()`, so in my case `User.class` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If the error only occurs on one device, it's most likely a bug on that device. If you report such problems to us at Saikoa, preferably with a small sample project, we may be able to let DexGuard work around it. You could check if building with the latest update makes a difference.

(I am the developer of DexGuard)

Comment: Thank you for your support. I will contact you soon

Comment: I am using... Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, ArrayList<Station>>>() {
            }.getType(); .. which does give me this list but i get Station object null what should i do

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be solved by using a different way to create the TypeToken instance (for the parameterized type `List<User>`):

```
Type collectionType = 
  TypeToken.get(
    $Gson$Types.newParameterizedTypeWithOwner(null,
      List.class, User.class)).getType();

new Gson().fromJson(json, collectionType);
```

The next version of gson (I assume 2.8), will allow you to type this more easily:

```
Type collectionType =
  TypeToken.getParameterized(List.class,
                             User.class).getType();
new Gson().fromJson(json, collectionType);
```

For non-parameterized classes, the following can be used:

```
new Gson().fromJson(json, TypeToken.get(Config.class).getType());
```